# Jmeter JSON PATH postprocessor

Tags: json, jmeter

I have my JSON response code as

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="RequestScript">
var contextpath = 'https://example.com/';
var JSONObject = null;
var XMLString ='';
var pswitchprofiles = new Object();

pswitchprofiles.WLDATAObject =
{
:   switchprofile:
:   {
:   :   totalRows:5,
:   :   moreRows:false,
:   :   rows:
:   :   [
:   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   id:'1f04b8c7788f47eaba507cd1f01bafd6',
:   :   :   :   ex:'N',
:   :   :   :   name:'Mahindra'
:   :   :   },
:   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   id:'a316419bf71f402cbc3a7af746d80626',
:   :   :   :   ex:'N',
:   :   :   :   name:'Toyota'
:   :   :   },
:   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   id:'1b8f642c00c6469cad1f73829d1b88df',
:   :   :   :   ex:'N',
:   :   :   :   name:'Renault'
:   :   :   },
:   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   id:'df989db921f84dfcac2fb1d4e72c18a3',
:   :   :   :   ex:'N',
:   :   :   :   name:'Huyndai'
:   :   :   },
:   :   :   {
:   :   :   :   id:'43B014C9BF0C1516E0530100007F2995',
:   :   :   :   ex:'N',
:   :   :   :   name:'Skoda'
:   :   :   }
:   :   ]
:   }
}
;
</script>
```

I am trying to get the id for the corresponding name.
In JSON PATH postprocessor, if i give          $.switchprofile.rows[?(@.name == 'Renault')].id               in JSON path expressions, I am not able to get the correct id.

Please help me in getting it. Also, i am not sure if that response is actually JSON.
I am using jmeter 3.0

Comment: Look at the top of your response (type="text/javascript"). It's not json.

Comment: Thank you Ivan for your reply.
Now, how can i get the id value corresponding to that of name=Renault, if it is not json.

Comment: If i go for Regular expression extractor and use **id:'(.*?)',ex:'N',name:'Renault'}** i get the response as 

Match count: 1

Match[1][0]=id:'1f04b8c7788f47eaba507cd1f01bafd6',ex:'N',name:'Mahindra'},{id:'a316419bf71f402cbc3a7af746d80626',ex:'N',name:'Toyota'},{id:'1b8f642c00c6469cad1f73829d1b88df',ex:'N',name:'Renault'}

Match[1][1]=1f04b8c7788f47eaba507cd1f01bafd6',ex:'N',name:'Mahindra'},{id:'a316419bf71f402cbc3a7af746d80626',ex:'N',name:'Toyota'},{id:'1b8f642c00c6469cad1f73829d1b88df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is not JSON one therefore you won't be able to use JSON Path PostProcessor, you will need to switch to Regular Expression Extractor instead.

The relevant regular expression would look like:

```
id:'(\w+)',\s.*,\s.*name:'Renault'
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#regex)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: The response i sent you is from JSON response data. 
when i change the response data to regular expression tester, i get without spaces and colon.

In that i am getting match count : 0 if i use id:'(\w+)',\s.*,\s.*name:'Renault'

Comment: Regular expression tester code :
'<script type="text/javascript" id="RequestScript">
var pswitchprofiles = new Object();
pswitchprofiles.WLDATAObject =
{switchprofile:{totalRows:5,moreRows:false,rows:[{id:'1f04b8c7788f47eaba507cd1f01bafd6',ex:'N',name:'Mahindra'},{id:'a316419bf71f402cbc3a7af746d80626',ex:'N',name:'Toyota'},{id:'1b8f642c00c6469cad1f73829d1b88df',ex:'N',name:'Renault'},{id:'df989db921f84dfcac2fb1d4e72c18a3',ex:'N',name:'Huyndai'},{id:'43B014C9BF0C1516E0530100007F2995',ex:'N',name:'Skoda'}]}};</script>'

Comment: regular expressions are very fragile and sensitive to any markup changes,  you need to provide the full response as it is in order to get advice

Answer (score 0):

When i use Regular expression extactor with expression **id:'(\w*)',ex:'N',name:'Renault'** i am able to get my id properly.

Thanks @Dmitri for your help.